# boost/lexical_cast.hpp not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

In a different project which I unfortunately deleted, I was able to use Boost. 
I added the libaries in the project configuration, and then I declared

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Everything was fine.

Now in my new project I am getting the error

```
boost/lexical_cast.hpp not found
```

I have followed the instruction on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-from-within-the-visual-studio-ide

I have added my path to boost_1_58_0\libs to Linker->General->Additional Libraries.

However, now the above error is thrown by the compiler.

Does anybody have any idea what I might have done wrong?
I have not changed anything in regards of Boost.

Comment: "I have added my path to boost_1_58_0\libs to Linker->General->Additional Libraries". Have you added the include directory, though? Because `lexical_cast` doesn't need a library. It **does** need the headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're reading the wrong chapter.**

That chapter is about linking Boost object files to your project, but *Boost.LexicalCast* is a header-only library, for which [the introductory IDE set up instructions (on the same page) are relevant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide).

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. The instructions on the Boost website were wrong.

The ones found here are correct:
https://elektron9.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/configuring-c-boost-libraries-for-visual-studio/

I had to do the following additionally to make it work:

C/C++
All Options
Additional Include libraries
Add path to Boost there (not to Boost/lib or Boost/libs as the official docu says!)

Comment: The instructions are not "wrong"; you were reading the wrong chapter. You read the chapter on linking, which is completely irrelevant for header-only libs. (Crucially, you obviously didn't read the _whole_ page before complaining, which seems incredibly short-sighted.) [Try section 4.1 instead](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide).